# __finally in C++ Builder 2010 losing scope?

Tags: scope, c++builder, try-catch-finally

Here is a very strange thing which I don't think should happen:

```
UnicodeString test = "abc";

try
    {
    try
        {
        int a = 123;
        return a;   // This seems to produce a problem with "test" variable scope
        }
    catch (Exception &e)
        {
        // Some exception handler here
        }
    }
__finally
    {
    // At this point the "test" variable should still be in scope???
    test = "xyz"; // PROBLEM here - test is NULL instead of "abc"! Why?
    }
```

If I remove the `return a;` in the `try-catch` block the test variable is still defined. Is there a particular reason why after the above construct the UnicodeString seems to go out of scope? Is it a bug with C++ Builder 2010? I understand that return returns from function but it should still retain variable scope in the `__finally` block shouldn't it?

Comment: This happens also on C++Builder XE5, FWIW.

Comment: This same issue was discussed yesterday in the Embarcadero forum, where I provided an analysis of what the compiler is doing: [Why is UnicodeString losing scope in this example?](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=110377).

Comment: Stack unwinding has always been buggy in bcc32; e.g. [this bug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27117266/1505939) has been around for donkey's years and is still present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a bit more analysis and it seams that once you execute `return` statement all local objects from stack are acting as destroyed. If you try using heap objects instead this won't happen.

```
UnicodeString *test = new UnicodeString("abc");

try
    {
    try
        {
         int a = 123;
        return a;   // This seems to produce a problem with "test" variable scope
        }
    catch (Exception &e)
        {
        // Some exception handler here
        }
    }
__finally
    {
    ShowMessage(*test); // "abc" 
    *test = "xyz"; 
    }
delete test;
```

Using smart pointers like `unique_ptr` will again result in loosing an object in `__finally` since `return` will initiate it's destruction.

Comment: Thanks for investigating this. It seems this is a bug in C++ Builder 2010 as the variable should still stay in scope as it happens for vectors too. I will use workaround solutions.

Comment: The memory allocated by `new` is never `delete`d in this code, causing a memory leak.  I guess `delete test;` should actually be inside the `__finally` block.

Comment: Also it's not clear to me whether C++Builder guarantees that `test` still retains its same pointer value in this case (perhaps Remy would know)

Answer (score 1):

(Remy [posted](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=110377) this in comments but did not post an answer here)

When a `return` statement is hit within a `try...finally` block, what happens is that any local objects are destroyed (as they would be for any other `return`) **before** the `__finally` block is entered.

So by the time your code gets up to `test = "xyz";`, `test` has already been destroyed, causing undefined behaviour.

I guess it is a matter of semantics whether you call this a bug or a design flaw, but either way it is something to bear in mind when using `try...finally`. My personal advice would be to just not use it at all;  the Standard C++ techniques of `try...catch` and RAII can solve any problem.